# Angular expression inside of an inline html UI Bootsrap tooltip

Tags: angular-ui-bootstrap

I can't figure out the proper method to render angular expressions inside of uib-tooltip-html. The example used in the documentation: `<a href="#" uib-tooltip-html="'static. {{dynamicTooltipText}}. <b>bold.</b>'">inline string</a>`
doesn't work for me in IE, Chrome or Firefox. Can anyone point me in the right direction? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an excerpt from the docs

> uib-popover-html - Takes an expression that evaluates to an HTML string. Note that this HTML is not compiled. If compilation is required, please use the uib-popover-template attribute option instead. The user is responsible for ensuring the content is safe to put into the DOM!

The interesting part is

> The user is responsible for ensuring the content is safe to put into the DOM!

Which basically means you should use the [$sce](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce) service to sanitize you HTML and pass it as an expression at your controller

```
$scope.dynamicTooltipText = "MY SUPER DYNAMIC TEXT"

$scope.htmlPopover = $sce.trustAsHtml('static. ' + $scope.dynamicTooltipText + ' . <b>bold.</b>');
```

and then pass `$htmlPopover` to your `uib-popover-html` directive

```
<button uib-popover-html="htmlPopover" popover-placement="bottom" class="btn btn-default">
    HTML Popover
</button>
```

[Demo plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/7MrfEc1zyiJTwYFRrat6?p=preview)

Comment: Thank you. I would have sworn that I had already tried that method. I was already using $sce to set some tooltip text in the controller. I must have had some incorrect syntax. Thanks again.